# How can I parse a specific cookie from this string in Java?

Tags: java

say I have the following string in a variable

```
cookie-one=someValue;HttpOnly;Secure;Path=/;SameSite=none, cookie-two=someOtherValue;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly, cookie-three=oneMoreValue;Path=/;Secure
```

and I want a substring from the name of a cookie that I choose say `cookie-two` and store the string up to the contents of that cookie.

So basically I need

```
cookie-two=someOtherValue;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
```

How can I get this substring out?

Comment: You should look into finding a cookie parser. Cookie strings are not regular languages IIRC so if you try naive splitting you might run into issues or security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score -1):

You can just separate the String by commas first to separate the cookies. For example if you wanted just the cookie that has the name `cookie-two`:

```
String s = "cookie-one=someValue;HttpOnly;Secure;Path=/;SameSite=none, cookie-two=someOtherValue;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly, cookie-three=oneMoreValue;Path=/;Secure";

String[] cookies = s.split(",");
for(String cookie : cookies){
  if(cookie.trim().startsWith("cookie-two")){
    System.out.println(cookie);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is possible to achieve in several different ways depending on how the data might vary in the sting. For your specific example we could for instance do like this:

```
String cookieString = "cookie-one=someValue;HttpOnly;Secure;Path=/;SameSite=none, cookie-two=someOtherValue;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly, cookie-three=oneMoreValue;Path=/;Secure";
String result = "";
for(String s: cookieString.split(", ")) {
    if(s.startsWith("cookie-two")) {
        result = s;
        break;
    }
}
```

We could also use regex and/or streams to make the code look nicer, but this is probably one of the most straight forward ways of achieving what you want.